# Angular material table - Error: can not find column

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to generate a table to learn how to use the table functionality offered by Angular Material but I am getting stucked at the moment. I am guessing it is something pretty basic which I am just overlooking. Hoping one of you wizards sees what I am doing wrong (ignore the navigating to an other page part as it's not yet implemented in the template).

I am getting the following error in my console:

```
ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "id".
```

The .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { MatSort } from "@angular/material/sort";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material/table";

import { metingen } from "../mocks/metingen.mock";

@Component({
  selector: "app-overzicht-metingen",
  template: `
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.datumVanDeMeting }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Weight</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.producttype }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class OverzichtMetingenComponent implements OnInit {
  // toevoegen van een meting
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["id", "datumVanDeMeting", "producttype"];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(metingen);

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  onSelect(id: string) {
    this.router.navigate(["/inzien-meting", id]);
  }
}
```

My file with the mocked data:

```
import { Meting } from "../models/meting";

export const metingen: Meting[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    datumVanDeMeting: new Date(),
    producttype: "variant A",
    sensor1: [1, 2, 3],
    sensor2: [2, 3, 4],
    sensor3: [3, 4, 5],
    sensor4: [4, 5, 6]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    datumVanDeMeting: new Date(),
    producttype: "variant B",
    sensor1: [3, 2, 2],
    sensor2: [4, 3, 3],
    sensor3: [5, 4, 4],
    sensor4: [6, 5, 5]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    datumVanDeMeting: new Date(),
    producttype: "variant A",
    sensor1: [9, 2, 9],
    sensor2: [8, 3, 8],
    sensor3: [7, 4, 7],
    sensor4: [6, 5, 6]
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    datumVanDeMeting: new Date(),
    producttype: "variant B",
    sensor1: [1, 4, 3],
    sensor2: [2, 3, 7],
    sensor3: [3, 9, 5],
    sensor4: [8, 5, 6]
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    datumVanDeMeting: new Date(),
    producttype: "variant A",
    sensor1: [7, 3, 3],
    sensor2: [2, 4, 7],
    sensor3: [8, 5, 5],
    sensor4: [4, 7, 9]
  }
];
```

Comment: if you put that displayedColumns is ["id",...] you need define a `<ng-container matColumnDef="id">` else remove from the array

Comment: See, something I completely missed. Would you by accident also know why the sort is not functioning if I change the code to [code]<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>id</th>[/code]

Comment: Fixed that follow up question. Seemed I also had to import the MatSortModule into my project.